# What will be the SQL query for this UPDATE operation?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am using MySql 5.1. i have to database tables Users and Users_group_mapping.

```
User Table :
    userid, username,   points
     1       user1       10
     2       user2       21
     3       user3       7
     4       user4       44

Users_group_mapping Table  :
    userid, usergroupid
     1       1
     2       2
     4       2
     4       1
     4       3
```

And in an allocation Process i have to allocate points to corresponding groups users.
For that test data is like :

```
Data : $dtArr = array(
    [1] => 40,
    [2] => 80,
    [3] => 100
)
```

In array $dtArr, the key is the attribute 'usergroupdid' in Users_group_mapping table and the value is the attribute points that to be updated in Users table.

e.g. if usergroupid = 2 and points to be given = 40
then from Users_group_mapping table the users in usergroup '2' - which are userids '2' & '4' - both users will get 40 points each.
userid '4' will get only 40 points allocated through usergroup '2' even though the user belongs to usergoups '1' & '3' also.

What will be the SQL Update query for this operation?

Please guide me..!! thanks in advance.!!

Comment: In "e.g. if groupid = 2 and points to be given = 40 then ", did you mean 80 instead of 40? What have you tried so far? What DB (SQL Server, Oracle, mysql) are you using?

Comment: which language do you use? if it has to be SQL that your allocation data should be in sql table

Comment: Also if you want the first occurance only you should tell in which order you are assigning points. In ofder of $dtArr or Users_group_mapping table? If the second is right than I would reccomend adding sort column to Users_group_mapping

Comment: you can't do it all with just one update, you should write a small cycle of update statements, storing the "aready updated" userid's somewhere so you can also check if they can get more points

Comment: wel, you can to it in one update if the data is in the database table, but the iterative approach is probably easier for you. I can help, with it, but you hould answer the questions above.

Comment: @shahkalpesh : all the users in group with groupid '2' will get 40 points. thats what i want.

gorn : I am using mysql 5.1 and points should be allocate according to first occurance in Users_group_mapping table

Comment: Errr - just one question: You have 80 points for group 2, why you want 40 to be given to users? If should be divided by number of users?

Answer (score 1):

If you have everything in database and if you really want to do it in order given by table 
Users_group_mapping, than you should add sequence column to this table and create new table `Data`. So you will have something like this:

```
User Table :
    userid, username,   points
     1       user1       10
     2       user2       21
     3       user3       7
     4       user4       44

Users_group_mapping Table  :
    userid, usergroupid  rowseq
     1       1            1
     2       2            2
     4       2            3
     4       1            4
     4       3            5

Data Table  :
    usergroupid, points
     1             40
     2             80  
     3            100
```

than the SQL which you require is as follows:

```
UPDATE User 
  JOIN Users_group_mapping USING (userid) 
  JOIN Data on Data.usergroupid=Users_group_mapping.usergroupid
  LEFT JOIN Users_group_mapping as x ON x.userid=User.userid and x.rowseq < Users_group_mapping.rowseq 
  SET User.points = User.points + Data.points
  WHERE x.userid IS NULL
```

if you do not want to **add** points to already existing points, but set them, than of course use

```
UPDATE User 
  JOIN Users_group_mapping USING (userid) 
  JOIN Data on Data.usergroupid=Users_group_mapping.usergroupid
  LEFT JOIN Users_group_mapping as x ON x.userid=User.userid and x.rowseq < Users_group_mapping.rowseq 
  SET User.points = Data.points
  WHERE x.userid IS NULL
```

**EDIT**

Here is the solution if you can not change the data structure (php+mysql)

```
$userids[] = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $userids[] = $user_row['userid'];
};

foreach($userids as $userid) {
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT usergroupid FROM  Users_group_mapping WHERE userid = $userid");
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));   # we only need first matching row so no cycle
  $usergroupid = intval($row['usergroupid']);
  $points = $dtArr[$usergroupid];
  mysql_query("UPDATE User SET points = points + $points WHERE User.userid = $userid");   
};
```

please not that although the code is correct, because it is not that hard to solve this, there will be some stupid mistakes (syntax errors etc) as I do not have time to debug it. But it should give you your answer.

Comment: I cant make any changes in structures of above database tables and the data_array $dtarr is available to me in PHP only.

Comment: well, than i will rewrite it in php, but I still think, that it is a good thing to include rowseq in your data. What if one day you will need to change the sequence in your Users_group_mapping table?

Comment: Errr - just one question: You have 80 points for group 2, why you want 40 to be given to users? If should be divided by number of users?

Comment: i have posted my second solution. Everyone in second group gets 80.